# rspec check any argument is hash including particular pair

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I have a shared rspec example for a number of functions (rest requests).  Each function receives a hash which I want to check, but they can be at different positions, e.g.:

```
get(url, payload, headers)
delete(url, headers)
```

I want to write the following test:

```
shared_examples_for "any request" do
  describe "sets user agent" do
    it "defaults to some value" do
        rest_client.should_receive(action).with(????)
        run_request
      end
      it "to value passed to constructor"
    end
  end
end

describe "#create" do
  let(:action) {:post}
  let (:run_action) {rest_client.post(url, payload, hash_i_care_about)}
  it_behaves_like "any request"
end
```

The question is, how can I write a matcher which matches any of the arguments, e.g.:

```
client.should_receive(action).with(arguments_including(hash_including(:user_agent => "my_agent")))
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to match any argument, you can pass a block to `should_receive` which can then check the arguments in any fashion you want:

```
client.should_receive(action) do |*args|
  # code to check that one of the args is the kind of hash you want
end
```

You could search the list of args for an argument of hash type, you could pass a parameter into the shared example indicating what position in the argument list the hash should exist in etc. Let me know if this is not clear and I can provide more detail.

This is covered briefly in https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/argument-matchers

Answer (score 0):

My example is a little bit in conjunction with what Peter Alfvin suggested:

```
shared_examples "any_request" do |**args|
  action = args[:action]
  url = args[:url]
  payload = args[:payload]
  headers = args[:headers]
  # ...etc

  case action
    when :get
    # code to carry on

    when :post
    # code to continue

  end
end
```

This way you can define and work with the arguments as your code expands, in any order and in any amount. You would call the function like so:

```
it_behaves_like "any_request", { action: :post,
                                 url: '/somewhere' }
```

Undeclared arguments, like `:payload` in this example would automatically carry the value of `nil`. Test its existence like: `if payload.nil?` or `unless payload.nil?` etc.

Note: This works for Ruby 2.0, Rails 4.0, rspec 2.13.1. Actual code definitions may vary on earlier versions.
Note_note: `... do |**args|` the two asterisks is not a typo ;)